# Connecting RPi to an iPhone through Bluetooth using an iOS app

Tags: bluetooth

My goal is to be able to use an app on my iPhone(made by me) to execute commands on my RPi. I know Swift fairly well, though I am not all that familiar with using Bluetooth and Swift(though I am confident that I can figure this out). Would this be possible? Could I connect to my RPi from Bluetooth, and then could I actually execute a terminal command?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As of now this quesiton is very broad (look at the two answers, I guess the don't help too much?). Please be more specific. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. You'll need an application on the RPi that monitors a Bluetooth dongle for traffic, and then execute commands based on what it receives from your phone.

How that's implemented is up to you.

Comment: What application? How do you monitor Bluetooth? You are not adding any new information.

Comment: @Fcm: they'd have to write an application. There's no magic bullet for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since the raspberry pi uses a version of Linux, I would write a script checking for incoming Bluetooth connections. Once you pair phone and raspberry pi, you will be sending data over the link. Also, consider whether Bluetooth is the best protocol. WiFi is higher performing speed wise, according to a brief Google search, so if you are, say, doing any high fidelity streaming or gaming, use WiFi.

Comment: Not answered. Please be more specific, what application, sample code, references. Opinions don't count.